# What is grunt-sass's dist option?

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs

I'm running `grunt-sass`and I've been searching the documentation and can't find what does the `dist` options stand for. What is this option?

```
grunt.initConfig({
    sass: {
        options: {
            sourceMap: true
        },
        dist: {
            files: {
                'main.css': 'main.scss'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As described in [setting-sass-grunt](http://culttt.com/2013/11/18/setting-sass-grunt/)

> The Sass configuration is basically broken down into two sections, dev
>   and dist for development and production. This allows us to set
>   different options for the different outputs depending on the
>   environment. For example, you will want your production stylesheets to
>   be compressed, but whilst in development we would want the output
>   which is generated to be expanded.

Comment: Thanks, this really helped :)